# How to list bibliography with []?

Tags: bibliographystyle

I use AIP template. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/aip-conference-proceedings/fpznwrhxkkpp

but the bibliography is like this

1. A. A. Anastassi. Constructing runge–kutta methods with the use of artificial neural networks. Neural Computing and Applications, 25(1):229–
   236, 2014.

I want like this

[1] A. A. Anastassi. Constructing runge–kutta methods with the use of artificial neural networks. Neural Computing and Applications, 25(1):229–
236, 2014.

How could I change this?

Comment: If you're writing for a conference, you should stick to their template. If you're not, why are you using that template? Anyway, if you simply *must* change things, you could try something like `\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1]\hspace*{0.5em}}`. (Compile multiple times.)

Comment: My conference used the AIP proceedings template. But there are differences in bibliographies.